# Why do we create universal turing machines?

Tags: turing-machines

Why do we create Universal Turing Machine explicilty to simulate the run of a word (say, $w$) on a Turing Machine $M$, given the description on it? Can't we just run $w$ on $M$ itself? I don't see the point of it.

Comment: A Truing Machine is a program, we can make a device that solves a unique problem, for example, we can create a turning machine(A device like boolean circuits) that checks if the input is prime or not. A UTM is a machine that you can reprogram and It is the point, reprogramming.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, the universal Turing machine $U$ was defined to prove the undecidability of certain problems. Roughly speaking, we're talking about a machine that is able to decide what any other Turing machine decides. So assuming that Turing machines fully capture the notion of decidability, then it holds that anything that can be decided, can also be decided by $U$. Conversely, any problem that is not decided by the universal machine $U$ is considered to be undecidable.

To be more concrete, the ability of $U$ to take as input an encoding of another machine $M$ and an input $w$ of $M$, enables us (the machine $U$) to ask questions about other machines $M$. For example, a consequence of this ability is that we can ask whether $M$ halts on $w$: is there a universal machine $U$ that decides whether $M$ halts on $w$? More formally, is there a machine $U$ that decides the language $Halt_{TM} = \{ \langle M, w\rangle: M \text{ is a TM and $M$ halts on the input $w$}\}$.

One, with a diagonalization argument, can prove that the $Halt_{TM}$ is undecidable. $Halt_{TM}$ is known as the halting problem: is there a program that eventually halts and tells us whether another program (which is given as input) halts?

So, thanks to universal machines, we can ask all these interesting questions about machines, and get undecidability results.

Answer (score 1):

Basically we are interested in some generalized version of a Turing Machine. Universal Turing Machine is something that can solve any problem. It just needs to be programmed. That's why when we Define a Universal Turing Machine, we write $U(M,x)$, where we say $M(x)=1$ means accept and otherwise reject. Here $M$ can be seen as some program written by some programmer, which we are not interested about. You can think it as your PC, where you can do a lot of stuffs. Some programs are there, some are not. Suppose you install some software, which can be seen as a Turing Machine and your PC is an Universal Turing Machine.

Answer (score 1):

Your desktop computer and your smart phone are Univeral Turing machines because they can be programmed to do whatever we want. That's the point of having Unviersal Turing machines.

If we did not have Universal Turing machines, then instead of just downloading and installing another app (in other words, a word $w$ to be simulated), you would have to buy a new computer every time you wanted new functionality. You'd have a whole lot of computers at home.